# How to use programs on a restricted internet connection

Tags: windows-8, proxy, internet-connection, tor, steam

My current internet connection blocks certain websites (Including steampowered.com) and to access these websites I use tor browser (using meek-google). Is there any way to use programs like steam on my restricted connection to update games?

Comment: it would depend on the type of firewall and settings, generally it's best not to attempt to get past these unless you have permission (in which case admin would normally open it up for you anyway). Generally a bad idea because a lot of firewalls will log what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kilisi I've been using tor to bypass restrictions on websites for ages, I'm not worried about that.

Comment: in that case a VPN is one way you could accomplish it, this would be the best way of having full access anyway, fiddling around with proxies are another

Comment: How would I accomplish that? I already have the proxy I need to connect to, is it something I can do in Windows or do I need a program? @Kilisi

Comment: you can do it in Windows easily enough, slightly different on diff versions, best to look up the steps in a search engine

Comment: Someone mentioned proxifier, anyone had any experience with that program?

Answer (score 0):

I work out of my office a lot and often need to access sites that are being blocked by the places I'm working at. In these cases I have both a VPN and teamviewer on my office machine and can remote in and do whatever I need to do.

I don't have much experience with proxies except how to block them from the firewall and log attempts to use them. But VPN serves all my needs just fine if the bandwidth is ok.

Comment: Good, but how do I accomplish this? The vpn option not RDP

Comment: many many ways to do so, best to look up which one suits you, I'm not familiar with gaming sorry. Just enter VPN methods into a search engine.